# How do I filter from two models (one to one) in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models with 1-1 relationship, User and deviceInfo. I am trying to query to get all Users with a specific device ID, and also only guests.

My Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=101,primary_key=True)
    guest = models.BooleanField()


class deviceInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique = True)
    deviceID = models.CharField(max_length=101, default=None)
```

So far I figured out how to filter by device ID. But im not sure how i'd filter this further because the guest value is in another model.

What I have so far: (only filters device id)

```
numIDs = deviceInfo.objects.filter(deviceID=deviceId).count()
```

What I tried: (doesn't work)

```
User.objects.filter(deviceInfo = numID)
```

I get the error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Comment: Can you show `LoggedUserInfo` model

Comment: Sorry, I just renamed LoggedUserInfo to deviceInfo for clarity, forgot to edit it everywhere, fixed it now.  (Question is now solved by NKSM)

Comment: Tagging both [tag:postgresql] and [tag:sqlite] hasn't convinced me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
User.objects.filter(guest=True, deviceinfo__deviceID=deviceId)
```

or if you need only user IDs

```
user_ids = deviceInfo.objects.filter(deviceId=deviceId, user__guest=True).values_list("user", flat=True)
User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
```

See Django: **[Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)**